# How to pass variable Tags in a robotfranework testcase?

Tags: robotframework

I have automated test which takes input from the user and runs the test. Any idea on if we can provide variable testcase Tags into it ?
Eg: 
`My robot testcase

 [Tags]  ${mytag}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Set Tags](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Tags) keyword to set the tags for a test case based on user input.

For example, assuming you define a variable named `${mytag}`, you can add it to the testcase like this:

```
| | Set tags | ${mytag}
```